# Expand (json) object in php

Tags: php

I want this sql-query result (from a log file, i hope it's accurate)

```
[
 {"id":"1","text":"123"}
,{"id":"2","text":"456"}
] []
```

to become this

```
{
 1: {"id":"1","text":"123"}
,2: {"id":"2","text":"456"}
}
```

I tried array_push and array_combine but am new to PHP and was unsuccessful so far.
Short: I want to add keys (starting with 1) to an array of objects.

One attempt

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = fetchRow($result)) {            
            array_push($arr_result, $row);
            array_push($i, $arr_result);
            $i++;
        }
```

But $arr_result looks like the first code sample.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: try `echo json_decode($your_string,true);`

Comment: If using built-in functions was unsuccessful, what about giving a try to a *good old loop* ?

Comment: `$arr_result[$i] = $row;`

Comment: @cid Thanks - that worked but the keys are now text instead of integers, right?

Comment: keys are always strings in JSON. Otherwise it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Why do you need/want this transformation anyway? The ID is already transmitted in the original data format. You're not adding any information.

Comment: @ADyson The object is consumed by an application to populate a table. The schema is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need `$i` using `$arr_result[]` will create a new occurance in your array.

```
while ($row = fetchRow($result)) { 
    // this forces the array to start at 1 instead of 0 if thats what you really want
    if (count($arr_result) == 0){
        $arr_result[1] = $row;
    } else {
        $arr_result[] = $row;
    }           
}
```

Or if the key is supposed to be the `id` from the row

```
while ($row = fetchRow($result)) { 
    $arr_result[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

Comment: For some reasons, OP wants the array to be 1 indexed

Comment: @Cid Thanks, pretty sure the OP does not really know what they really want but the questions does indicate that you are right

Comment: @Cid Or maybe they wanted it to be the value of the `id`